# 1D convolution for uni-variate data

Tags: python, convolution

Every one. I have EEG dataset with 80 subjects, 3072 data points and 100 trials. This a univariate data, it mean there is only one channel. I am confused how to feed this data to convolution neural network.
 Most of blog and tutorial deals with multivariate data. But i have univariate and i am clueless how to move ahead

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following image ([original link](https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf)) will be helpful to understand. 1D convolutions work exactly the same way as 2D convolutions, the main difference is how the filter/mask is applied. 1D convolution is intuitively like a sliding window of a certain width.

Many packages like Keras or PyTorch have native 1D convolution function/modules, so I would recommend checking their documentation and perhaps source code for deeper understanding.

[image: https://blog.goodaudience.com/introduction-to-1d-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras-for-time-sequences-3a7ff801a2cf]

Comment: i have already checked those, they talk about channels, which i dont have . i have just one channel

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are having problems with specifying the "input_shape" parameter in the first layer properly? Number of channels only take part there so that's probably the issue.

Check [this](https://github.com/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%204%20-%20S%2BP/S%2BP%20Week%204%20Exercise%20Answer.ipynb) notebook for a 1 dimensional CNN example for univariate data.

Edit: Ok, it is actually a mixed NN with first layer a CNN. But still it should help with the input layer. Let me know if that helps. There must be a CNN somewhere in that folder.